# Explicitly proving invariance of curvatures under isometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I would like to know how to explicitly prove that Riemann Curvature,Ricci Curvature, Sectional Curvature and Scalar Curvature are left invariant under an isometry.

I can't see this explained in most books I have looked at. 
They atmost explain preservation of the connection.

I guess doing an explicit proof for the sectional curvature should be enough (and easiest?) since all the rest can be written in terms of it.

---

Given Akhil's reply I think I should try to understand the connection invariance proof better and here goes my partial attempt.

Let $\nabla$ be the connection on the manifold $(M,g)$ and $\nabla '$ be the Riemann connection on the manifold $(M',g')$ and between these two let $\phi$ be the isometry. Then one wants to show two things,

- $D\phi [\nabla _ X Y] = \nabla ' _{D\phi[X]} D\phi [Y]$
- $R(X,Y)Z = R'(D\phi [X],D\phi [Y]) D\phi [Z]$

Where $R$ and $R'$ are the Riemann connection on $(M,g)$ and $(M',g')$ respectively.

One defines the map $\nabla ''$ on M which maps two vector fields on M to another vector field using $\nabla '' _X Y = D\phi ^{-1} (\nabla' _{D\phi[X]} D\phi [Y]$. By the uniqueness of the Riemann connection the proof is complete if one can show that this $\nabla ''$ satisfies all the conditions of being a Riemann connection on M.

I am getting stuck after a few steps while trying to show the Lebnitz property of $\nabla ''$. Let $f$ be some smooth function on M and then one would like to show that,
$\nabla '' _X fY = X(f)Y + f\nabla '' _X Y$ which is equivalent to showing that,
$D\phi ^{-1} (\nabla' _{D\phi[X]} D\phi [fY]) = X(f) + f D\phi ^{-1} (\nabla' _{D\phi[X]} D\phi [Y])$ knowing that $\nabla '$ satisfies the Leibniz property on $M'$.

Some how I am not being able to unwrap the above to prove this.
I can get the second term of the equation but not the first one.

Proving symmetry of $\nabla ''$ is easy but again proving metric compatibility is stuck for me. If $X,Y,Z$ are 3 vector fields on M then one would want to show that,

$Xg(Y,Z) = g(\nabla ''_X Y,Z) + g(Y, \nabla '' _X Z)$

which is equivalent to showing that,

$Xg(Y,Z) = g(D\phi ^{-1} (\nabla' _{D\phi[X]} D\phi [Y]),Z) + g(Y,D\phi ^{-1} (\nabla' _{D\phi[X]} D\phi [Z]) )$

knowing that $\nabla'$ satisfies metric compatibility equation on $M'$

It would be helpful if someone can help me fill in the steps.

Then one is left with proving the curvature endomorphism equation.

Comment: All of this follows from the preservation of the curvature tensor under an isometry; indeed, if you pull back the Levi-Civita connection by an isometry, you get an invariant connection on the other manifold, so by uniqueness, the isometry preserves the connection. Since the curvatures are all derived from the connection, the claim follows.

Comment: @Akhil Thanks for your reply. Then I think I should try to understand the proof of invariance of the connection better. I have typed in above some of the steps of the proof as I can imagine it. It would be very helpful if you can fill in the missing steps.

Comment: Use the fact that $D\phi(fY) = f\circ \phi^{-1} D\phi(Y)$.  Now apply the Leibniz rule for $\nabla'$.  I suggest that you spend more time playing around with $\phi$ and understanding how it and its various incarnations (such as $D\phi$) interact with various constructions.  For example, in trying to prove metric compatibility, you will need to use the fact that $\phi$ is an isometry.  Try to phrase this condition in terms of a formula (involving $g, g', D\phi$ and tangent vectors).

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the help. I couldn't really understand your comment about the rewriting you suggested for the metric compatibility proof. Can you suggest some references along these lines?

Comment: @Matt $\phi ^{-1}$ is a map from the target manifold to the domain manifold. How does that act on $D\phi [Y]$? Do you mean a pull-back of $D\phi [Y]$ along $\phi$? Then how does a $f$ compose with the pulled back vector as you seem to indicate with the $\circ$ symbol? I am very confused by your notation.

Comment: Dear Anirbit, You are starting with the product $f Y$ (with $f$ a function on the source and $Y$ a tangent vector on the source).  You apply
$D\phi$ (pushforward along $\phi$) to a function on the target.
This is the product of the function $f\circ \phi^{-1}$ (a function on the target) and $D\phi(Y)$ (a tanget vector on the
target).

Comment: @Matt Let me make explicit the point $p \in M$ where I am evaluating the function. The the RHS is $D\phi (p) [f(p)Y_p]$ Then on which point on $N$ is the function $f\circ \phi ^{-1}$ being evaluated? Can you give a reference for this. Its curious that I didn't see this formula in even some advanced calculus books!

Comment: @Matt So the the fact that $\phi$ is an isometry is not needed to prove the Leibnitz property, but will only be required to prove metric compatibility. right?

Comment: @Matt Then the eventual claim is that the following holds, 

$D \phi ^{-1}[D\phi [X]\\(f \circ \phi ^{-1}\\) D \phi [Y]] = X(f)Y$

right? And I don't see why the above expression should be true.

Comment: Dear Anirbit, I think you should think a little more about what the various symbols you are manipulating mean, and how to test if they are equal.  For example, why are you applying $D\phi^{-1}$?  This just adds an extra layer of clutter to the equation you are trying to verify.   To be more precise about what I mean: to test if two tangent vectors are equal, you choose a function, and evaluate them on that function.  So to test equality of 
$(f\circ \phi^{-1})D_{\phi}(X)$ and $D\phi( fX),$ you should choose a function $g$ on $N$, apply both expressions to $g$,
unwind the definitions, ...

Comment: ... and check that they are the same.  You will find that you have two functions on $N$ which you must check are the same.  For this,
you choose a point $q \in N$, apply these two functions to $q$,
and check that the values are the same.  For *this*, you unwind the definitions again, etc. ... .  I think that if you are having  trouble  unwinding the definitions in this case, you should try something easier first.  For example, can you
verify that $D(\phi\circ \psi) = D\phi\circ D\psi$ for functions
$\psi:L \to M$ and $\phi: M \to N$?

Comment: Also, can you verify that if $X$ is a vector field on $M$ and $h$ is a function on $N$, then $((D\phi(X))(h))\circ \phi = X(h\circ \phi)?$  (Here $(D\phi)(X)$ is a vector field on $N$, so
$(D(\phi(X))(h)$, obtained by evaluating this vector field on the
function $h$, is a function on $h$.  Similarly, for the right hand side, $h\circ \phi$ is a function on $M$, and evaluating $X$
on this function gives another function on $M$.
These are similar exercises might be helpful warm-ups for your original question.

Comment: I am interested this question and i want to know can anyone complet this proof?and whats the answer of invariance sectional curvature under isometry.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the last big displayed equation under "formal definition" here.  It shows you Gauss's explicit form for a Levi-Civita connection in terms of the metric.  Since you know how the metric transforms under an isometry, and how a Lie bracket transforms under a diffeomorphism, working out how the connection transforms under an isometry amounts to putting those ingredients together.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection